# Add description for Serenity Junit Test

Tags: junit, serenity-bdd

I want to add description test for Serenity Junit test. Example consider below test

```
 @Test
 public void testSample()  {
    step.callStep();
    step.callStepTwo();

}
```

For above test, test name in Serenity html is "Test Sample". With that I want add a description. How to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

The test name should be a summary of the description.

Let's say you want to test a page's login feature. You can name the test as `testMyPageLoginFunction`.

If you don't want the test name to be so long and wordy, you can add a string that describes what the test is testing in the tag
`@Test("Your description here")`